# How can I retry an ajax request on empty response

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to retry an ajax request when response data is an empty json object.

My ajax code is following.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?r=funding/getPaymentButton",
        data: {email:benfEmail,data:JSON.stringify(data),paymentType:method},
        async: true,//false
        success: function (data) 
        { 
            if(data.length === 0)
            {
                $(this).ajax();//retry ajax request here, if data is empty
                console.log('err');
            }
            else
            {
                obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                // prcessing ajax request
            }
        }
});
```

PHP

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'type'=>$paymentType, 
    'btn'=>$this->PaymentBtn,
    'usd' => round($this->finalUSDAmount,2),)
);
```

Comment: why not wrap the ajax call in a function? then you can simply call the function from within the ajax call instead of the $(this).ajax() line

Comment: I am agree with @zoranc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your ajax request in a function and then call that function If the respons is empty.

Like this:

```
 function yourCall(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?r=funding/getPaymentButton",
        data: {email:benfEmail,data:JSON.stringify(data),paymentType:method},
        async: true,//false
        success: function (data) 
        { 
            if(data.length === 0)
            {
               yourCall();
               console.log('err');
            }
            else
            {
                obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                // prcessing ajax request
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

this setup will however keep trying the ajax call untill it gets a valid respons. This meaning that it will keep firing if the respons length == 0

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply Do Following:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'index.php?r=funding/getPaymentButton',
    type : 'POST',
    data :  {email:benfEmail,data:JSON.stringify(data),paymentType:method},   
    tryCount : 0,
    retryLimit : 3,
    success : function(json) {
        //do something
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
            this.tryCount++;
            if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                //try again
                $.ajax(this);
                return;
            }            
            return;
        }
        if (xhr.status == 500) {
            //handle error
        } else {
            //handle error
        }
    }
});
```